# How to get a Facebook access token that grants permission for an event endpoint?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

How can I get a Facebook access token that will grant permission to request information on events that the user has RSVP'd to (interested or attending)?   My current method works for my user, but not other users.

**My current method:**

I'm using the Facebook Javascript SDK to log in as a user, get an access token, and then query the graph API to get data about events that the user has logged into.

The route I'm hitting to get event data is (pseudo):

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/event

Or in my code (pseudo)

> https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/{event-id}?{access-token}&fields={fields}

When the app logs in as my own user (also admin of app), I get an access token that can be used to query the event route successfully, but when it logs in with another user, I get a failure when hitting the event route with the API token I receive:

> "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '466582570713258' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation."

According to Facebook's API documentation, it states that my app needs the user_events permission to hit the event api endpoint that I'm looking for:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/event

I went through the verify process and requested that permission for my app, which now has these approved:

```
PERMISSIONS
email
Provides access to the person's primary email address. This permission is approved by default.
public_profile
Provides access to a person's name and profile picture. This permission is approved by default.
user_events
Provides access to a person's events.
```

If I grab the API token I get back when logging in as a user (other than myself), it does say that user_events scope was granted, which would seem to be sufficient to get a response from the event endpoint.  But it is failing as above.

Comment: What is the relation between that “test user” you are logging in with, and the event? (And do you mean an actual _test user_, or a real account that was added to the app in a tester role?)

Comment: The user is just a regular Facebook user.   They RSVP'd to the event as "Interested" (same thing applies when "Attending")

Comment: And the event in question belongs to whom?

Comment: The same error happens with events created by any user, at least any user I've attempted (probably ~5 different events).  The API only says that they have to be visible.  Which they are.

Comment: user_events actually has a note in the docs: "This permission is restricted to a limited set of partners and usage requires prior approval by Facebook." so you sure your app had been approved for it?

Comment: Yes, I went through the approval process, and see that permission on my apps "My Permissions and Features" page.